# CentOS 7 Crash on boot

Tags: linux, centos, boot, kernel-panic

Getting this message attempting to boot CentOS 7

```
BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 000000000000009B
```

And then a kernel panic

Happens when trying to boot from the OS HDD or from the CentOS 7 CD in rescue mode.

Kernel Version: 3.10-123

I would like to recover this installation if I can instead of completely reinstalling/configuring this server again.  Everything was working fine last night, and this morning, KA-BOOM!

I'll be happy to provide whatever information I can.  unfortunately log entries are not available since I can't even get the system booted.

Update: I have tried booting into different runlevels.  All result with the same kernel panic.

Comment: What kind of hardware are we looking at?

Comment: Run the memory checker (from CD if necessary)

Comment: Boot with a previous kernel.

Comment: This happens even when booting from the CD? Do you boot directly from the CD or are you using the installed bootloader to find the CD or local iso?

Comment: This is not a real solution to your problem, just a pragmatic advice -- try booting from a different medium using a different kernel, and check for hardware problems. If there seem to be none, restore from your backup and save yourself the time tracking this down.

Comment: @fukawi2 Asus A55M-E Motherboard, AMD A8-5600K., Patriot Viper Xtreme DDR3 4GB, 1TB Mirror

Comment: @garethTheRed No other kernels on the system, system has been update for roughly a bit over a week.  Was originally CentOS 6.5 which ran for about 6 months.  I reinstalled/upgraded to CentOS 7, primarily as an excercise.

Comment: @terdon Direct from CD, F8 for boot device selection and select the DVD-ROM with the installation media.

Comment: @Anthon Ran memtest86+ from bootable disc, no errors found

Comment: @Wranorn It might still be a hardware problem, but I would tend to think something went wrong with a software update/configuration change. I don't think there is a boilerplate general way on how to solve that with such little information. If you can boot from CD/USB you can copy and save the non-backup data, so you at least have that in case you decide to do a reinstall.

Comment: @Anthon I fear I may have to do just that, just hoping to avoid it.

Comment: @Wranorn I have my data on a separate partition, mostly so I can just reinstall the OS ( I keep a changelog of everything needed to get things "my way"), so it is relatively easy to reinstall or to make a complete upgrade. In fact I have three 20Gb partitions for installing distros and can play around, keep a broken install for further analysis (and copy over config files that I forgot to mention in the changelog ;-) ) Every second year or so this comes in handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you interested.  Turns out there was some kind of corruption of the LVM.  My guess is due to me resizing the LVM partitions.  Managed to get a Live CD of CentOS 7 booting and every time I try to mount the partition I need, I receive the Kernel Panic.  So my tip to anyone.  If you have resized your LVM partitions this is likely the cause for the panic.